# Unable to send password and username

Tags: login

Unable to send root and password after telnet.  Why?

```
telnet board
sleep 3
echo -e "root\n"
sleep 1
echo -e "labrat\n"
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script

Comment: You... *do* know that the way shell script commands are utilized it won't really do anything until `telnet` exits, right?  So therefore it's not going to dump your messages into the telnet session properly?  Or are you using some other script mechanisms here?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a "simple" bash script to interact with a `telnet` session.

As per @Melebius comment, the answers [to this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts) propose some solutions, like using [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). As a simpler alternative you can pipe your commands *to* `telnet`:

```
{ sleep 3 ; echo "root" ; sleep 1 ; echo "labrat" ; sleep 1; } | telnet board
```

Please keep in mind that this way the telnet session terminates soon after the input is processed. If you want to create an *automated* script, it might be enough (but then `expect` is still a better way).

#### EDIT as per comments

<strike>If instead you want to open an *interactive* `telnet` session, but save yourself the "hassle" of entering username and password every time, I'm afraid there's not a simple solution. You can pass the username via the `-l` flag (i.e. `telnet -l root board`) so
you need to enter only the password.</strike>

Looks like `expect` can be used successfully to automate telnet logins while leaving an interactive prompt via the `interact` directive.

A simple example based would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn telnet board
sleep .3;
expect "login:"
send "root\r"
expect "password:"
send "labrat\r";
interact
```

Just edit to your needs.

Comment: “If instead you want to open an interactive telnet session” Expect seems to be able to work here, too. There are more examples of using SSH (e.g. https://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial) but it should work similarly with Telnet.

Comment: @Melebius you're right. Never used expect to leave an interactive prompt. Editing my question right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue (never used telnet myself), but `echo` already adds a newline when printing, so `echo -e "root\n"` will print `root` then two newlines. You probably want just one, so use `echo "root"` or `printf 'root\n'` instead.